# Meaning of option `fabric-ca-server -d`?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

The `fabric-samples` test network setup for fabric-ca-server (found in `fabric-samples/test-network/docker/docker-compose-ca.yaml`) initializes the certificate server with

```yaml
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
```

The option `-b` is clear in meaning - as shown in the output from `--help` and [the online copy of that](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/servercli.html), it's a user/password for bootstrapping the config file. The `-d` flag, however, is completely undocumented. What does it do?

Comment: Someone elsewhere suggested it is undefined and a no-op. Unclear why it's accepted if so. I can't find definitions of the flags that *are* used so unsure if that's correct.

Comment: It turns on debug logging for fabric-ca-server you get info level logging only without it

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/4c5d2ef98f6109ecceaa02e7b04aebe02fdff86f/docs/source/deployguide/cadeploy.md#start-the-tls-ca-server so it does! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the flag to enable debug mode; see [Deploy Guide](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/8b815daa5620516fd5ff0bd58d35e802cc468f24/docs/source/deployguide/cadeploy.md#start-the-tls-ca-server), *Start the TLS CA server*:

> *Optional flags:*
>
> - `-d` - If you want to run the server in DEBUG mode which facilitates problem diagnosis, you can include the -d flag on the start command. However, in general it is not recommended to run a server with debug enabled as this will cause the server to perform slower.
> - `-p` - If you want the server to run on a port different than what is specified in the configuration .yaml file, you can override the existing port.

The option is defined [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/8b815daa5620516fd5ff0bd58d35e802cc468f24/lib/serverconfig.go#L37) as a tag, and parsed [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/8b815daa5620516fd5ff0bd58d35e802cc468f24/util/flag.go#L58). For unknown reasons, it is set to be hidden from `fabric-ca-server --help`.

(h/t @david_k)